# iOS Keyboard extension - adding buttons to standard keyboard (system-wide input accessory view)

Tags: ios, ios-keyboard-extension, inputaccessoryview

Based on [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html) I know that I can implement a custom system-wide keyboard by implementing keyboard extension.

However, when working only in application scope, we are recommended to use custom [input views](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html). In app-scope, we have an option to implement just an input accessory view, in case we just want to add a couple of buttons to a standard keyboard.

Now I am standing before a task in which seems I would very much benefit from something like a system-wide accessory input view. I need only to add a couple of buttons to the standard keyboard, but it needs to be accessible in system wide scope. The only way to get it seems to be implementing my own custom keyboard extension in which I would need to lay out and implement the full fledged keyboard, and then add those custom buttons on top of it. But I would very much like to avoid implementing my own "standard" keyboard and just piggy-back either on standard keyboard (using something like system-wide keyboard). Is there a standard way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard Extension: Is it possible to inherit features and UI from the stock iOS keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004198/keyboard-extension-is-it-possible-to-inherit-features-and-ui-from-the-stock-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far it seems the fastest way would be taking one of the open source keyboards mimicking the standard keyboard, e.g., [Tasty Imitation Keyboard](https://github.com/archagon/tasty-imitation-keyboard), and modifying it to my own needs. It would be better than having to reimplement the whole keyboard on my own, yet, I would still like to find a way how to extend the standard keyboard.